# How to fix a JFace table to the SWT layout?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am creating a breadcrumb control in SWT which shows a bar at the top to search a location on the file system and a JFace table, using a TableViewer, below that bar to display the results i.e the folders and the files at the given location. The problem is once the data is loaded into the table and I try to maximize the window, the table collapses(sometimes disappears totally) leaving a empty space beneath it and making itself scroll-able. Below is the image before maximizing. [image]

And this happens after maximizing the window.

[image]
What should be done to correct this? Here is my code for creating the viewer.

```
DirectoryViewer container = new DirectoryViewer(this, SWT.BORDER|SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
GridData conData = new GridData();
conData .horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
conData.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
conData .grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
conData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
conData .horizontalSpan = 3;
container.getTable().setLayoutData(conData);
```

And the constructor of DirectoryViewer:

```
 public DirectoryViewer(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        Table table = getTable();
        GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        gridData .horizontalSpan = 3;
        table.setLayoutData(gridData);
        createColumns();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        setContentProvider(new ContentProvider());
    }
```

Comment: Not that it makes any difference, but why do you set the `LayoutData` of the `Table` twice?

Comment: @Baz I was checking whether this works or not :/

Comment: What kind of data structure is `DirectoryViewer`? Do you set its `LayoutData` somewhere?

Comment: @Baz its a class extending from TableViewer directly and No, i am not setting its layout anywhere.

Comment: If you're extending `TableViewer`, then you're fine. I don't see anything wrong with your code (at least with the part you provided).

Comment: @Baz one more thing, this problem does not arise before populating the table, in that case(empty table) it works perfectly fine :/

Comment: @Baz its done, actually I was doing something silly with my ModelProvider. I corrected that thing and eventually this problem also get solved.

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out.